# bash: how to add assigned value to file

Tags: text-processing, awk, variable

I have bash script looping through several files in a directory. The file identifier has been saved as a variable `$num`. What I would like to do is add `$num` as another column in my data like in the example below:

**ORIGINAL INPUT:**

```
A B C D E
2 79 56 SD L
1 09 67 JK S
9 60 37 KD G
0 10 47 SO E
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
A B C D E id
2 79 56 SD L 1
1 09 67 JK S 1
9 60 37 KD G 1
0 10 47 SO E 1
```

*in above example, `$num` = 1

Ultimately, I want to take a subset of lines from each looped file and cat them into a single large file. For me to know which file the line came from, I need the id from `$num`.

I have tried using `awk '{$12 = $num}' filename` but this does not work at all.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try (awk can be in one line)

```
 id=...
 awk -v id=$id 'NR==1 { x=NF+1 ; $x = "id" ; print ; }
                NR > 1 { x=NF+1 ; $x = id ; print ; } ' file > new_file
```

where

- `-v id=$id`  paste id from shell to awk, if id has funny char, use `-v id="îd"`
- `NR == 1` , `NR  > 1` select first, other line
- `{ x=NF+1 ; $x = id ; print ; }` push $id ( id in awk )

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

The following `sed` script assumes that the field separator is a space.  If it's a tab, change the space in both `s///` sed commands to `\t`.

The first line has `id` appended, second and subsequnt lines have `$num` appended.

```
$ num=1
$ sed -e "1 s/$/ id/ ; 2,$ s/$/ $num/" input.txt 
A B C D E id
2 79 56 SD L 1
1 09 67 JK S 1
9 60 37 KD G 1
0 10 47 SO E 1
```